# No need to close the window, If I press the cancel button in confirmation box?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my chat application,I need an confirmation box to logout when closing the window.

Ok button in confirmation box works fine.but,

If i press, cancel in the confirmation box,I dont need to close the browser window..

In my case if i press cancel ,My browser window was closed...Please help me...

```
window.onunload = function () {

    var confirmation = confirm("Are you Sur want to logout the session ?");
    if (confirmation == true)
      {
        if((sessionId != null)&&(sessionId!="null")&& (sessionId != ""))
            logout();
     // confirmation = "You pressed OK!";
      }
    else
      {
     // confirmation = "You pressed Cancel!";


      }
};
```

In logout code,

```
function logout(){
    //alert("<---------->"+userId+";"+secureKey+";"+name);
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById("button3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("message").innerText = "";
    try
    {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            //alert("Status : "+xmlhttp.status+"\nreadyState : "+xmlhttp.readyState);
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                //alert("<---------->"+userId+";"+secureKey+";"+name);
                //alert(xmlhttp.responseText.toString());
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","LogoutAction?&userId="+userId+"&secureKey="+secureKey+"&nickname="+name,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.description);
    }
}
```

In LogoutAction Servlet,

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        secureKey = request.getParameter("secureKey");
        userId = request.getParameter("userId");
        //nickname = request.getParameter(nickname);
        protocol = ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol;

        logout = new Logout();
        logout.requestLogout(secureKey, userId, null, protocol);
        //out.println(secureKey+";"+userId+";"+nickname);
    }
```

In java code,

```
public class Logout {
public void requestLogout(String secureKey, String userId, String nickname, FlexChatProtocol protocol) {

        RequestLogout logout = null;

        Message resp  = null;
        logout = RequestLogout.create();
        logout.setSecureKey(secureKey);
        logout.setUserId(userId);
            try {

            resp = protocol.request(logout);
            System.out.println(resp);


        } catch (ProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        } 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use onbeforeunload.. like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {

var confirmation = confirm("Are you Sur want to logout the session ?");
if (confirmation == true)
  {
    if((sessionId != null)&&(sessionId!="null")&& (sessionId != ""))
        logout();
 // confirmation = "You pressed OK!";
  }
else
  {
 // confirmation = "You pressed Cancel!";


  }
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent a user closing a window. This is actually a feature of browsers to prevent malicious sites keeping a window open. Think of what would happen with pop-up advertisements if you couldn't close the window.

Unload handlers can prevent the user navigating away, but not closing the window.

Comment: Then how to prevent the closing of window ?

Comment: You can't. The browser will not let you stop a user from closing the window. The best you can usually do is do something on unload to save the users state so they haven't lost too much if it was accidental.

Comment: If I press cancel i don't need to close the window.If I press ok only, I need to close the window..Where I have to modify my code?Pls help me...Its urgent...